# sql join with laravel query builder

Tags: mysql

I have a transactions table with the following field:

```
Transactions
ID | amount | branch_id | supplier_id 
1  | 1,200  |    2      |  1
```

---

```
Subsidiary
ID  | Name      | Type
1   | supplier1 | 0
2   | branch_2  | 1
```

---

I want to display this in my view with the id value properly so I joined the following table (I'm using laravel query builder)

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions_table')
->leftJoin('subsidiary_table','transactions_table.supplier_id','=','subsidiary_table.id')
->get(array('transactions_table.id',
'transactions_table.amount',
'subsidiary_table.name as branch',
'subsidiary_table.name as supplier'));
```

I'm confused on how can I get it to display like:

```
Display View
ID  |   Ammount  |  Supplier  | Branch 
1   |   1,200    |  Supplier1 | branch_2
```

Thanks for clarifying..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you want to put it in laravel, but, here's the query:

```
SELECT
 t.ID,
 t.amount,
 s.Name as Supplier,
 sb.Name as Branch
FROM Transactions as t
JOIN Subsidiary as s ON (s.ID=t.supplier_id)
JOIN Subsidiary as sb ON (sb.ID=t.branch_id)
WHERE t.ID = 1;
```

Try it.

PD: You can change the `JOIN` syntax for  `LEFT JOIN` if you want to return the `t.ID = 1` record from `Transactions` even if one column don't match in `Subsidiary's JOINs`.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the concept @oNare.. you code seems correct., my problem now is to convert it into the laravel's query builder.. :) thank you very much

Comment: I will still open the question, maybe someone would help me convert it into my desired result if so ..

Comment: I don't know if you looked in other sites, but, here two examples of how you can put this query in laravel query builder: 

1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079281/laravel-fluent-query-builder-join-with-subquery 
2 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773790/laravel-4-query-builder-with-complicated-left-joins

Comment: heheh.. yeah @oNare I searched on others sites, I guess my last resort is to use DB::select() and insert a row statement on it using your query.. I just thought I would be clearer if I used there query builder but it seems to be giving much more time to figure out.. anyways thanks again for your help.. I need to go rest after a long night of programming.. this question is just 1 of hundreds :) Good Nights

Comment: You can ask anything, we're here to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create view in Laravel using Eloquent/QueryBuilder. You have to use normal sql `CREATE VIEW` commands in migrations `up()` function. Kindly have a look at my detailed answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228483/how-to-combine-multiple-row-in-same-table-into-1-row-with-different-column-in-sq/31238624#31238624) of stackoverlflow (since its same question by same user there).